# How to remove Validation on button Click

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a page named register where the user can enter his username. password, name ... and on each textbox there is a text field validator and there is 2 buttons register and exit.

On the exit button i want to go back to the main page, but the problem is that I can't go back to the main page before putting all the info bcp of the validator, so how can I disable the text field validator on this button exit ?

Answer (score 1):

For your exit button, there is a property named `CausesValidation`.
Simply set it as `CausesValidation = false;`

Answer (score 0):

In case of asp.net Validator use `CausesValidation = false;` propert of button. By setting CauseValidation Property to false your button is no longer bound with asp.net validations.
 and if you are html5 Validation(`required`).  Then Simply write `formnovalidate` in you button.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ValidationGroup` property on your `TextBox`es and `Register` button and then use different `ValidationGroup` on `Exit` button.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Main"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rf1" ControlToValidate="txt1" runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="Required" ValidationGroup="Main"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Main"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rf2" ControlToValidate="txt2" runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="Required" ValidationGroup="Main"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Save"  ValidationGroup="Main"/>
<asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" Text="Exit"  ValidationGroup="NoMain"/>
```

I guess you can leave the `ValidationGroup` property of `Exit` button to blank, but I haven't tested it.